# Advanced multiple checkbox filter with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

I want to filter my content using checkboxes and I got some references from 'StackOverflow'. The following is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post').show();

  $('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var $posts = $('.post').hide();
    var $elements = $('.menu-item').find('input:checked');

    $posts.filter(function() {
        var $post = $(this);
        return $elements.toArray().every(function(element) {
          return $post.hasClass($(element).attr('id'));
        });
      })
      .show();
  });
});
```

```css
article {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
    <h4>Profession</h4>
    
        <label for="doctor">Doctor</label>
        <input id="doctor" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="engineer">Engineer</label>
        <input id="engineer" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="pilot">Pilot</label>
        <input id="pilot" type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
    <h4>City</h4>
    
        <label for="kochi">Kochi</label>
        <input id="kochi" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="trivandrum">Trivandrum</label>
        <input id="trivandrum" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="kannur">Kannur</label>
        <input id="kannur" type="checkbox" />
    </li>
</ul>
 <article class="post doctor kochi">doctor-kochi</article>
    <article class="post engineer kannur">Engineer-kannur</article>
    <article class="post pilot trivandrum">pilot-trivandrum</article>
    <article class="post doctor kannur">doctor-kannur</article>
    <article class="post enginner kochi">Engineer-kochi</article>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kichupreeji/rcyt19g8/12/

But my problem is, when I check doctor from checkbox it displays all doctor values and when I select Kannur and doctor it select doctor from Kannur, but when I select Kochi, Kannur, and doctor, it displays nothing. I want is when I select so, I need to display doctor from Kannur and Kochi. I knew that it could be done using by combining `array.every` and `array.some`, but I don't know about these functions. Any help would appreciable

Comment: Please can anyone help me

Comment: What's the overall goal? Do you want an 'or' search (checking `#kochi` and `#doctor` will find all elements with *either* of those class-names)? Or do you want an 'and' search (showing only those elements with *both* of those class-names)? How many options can be chosen from each set? If the user checks `#doctor`, `#pilot`, `#kochi`, `#kannur` and `#trivandrum` what should show?

Comment: when selects doctor,kochi trivandrum it shows doctor from kochi and trivandrum. simillarly when selects doctor,pilot,kochi,kannur it displays all doctor, pilot from kochi and kannur.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `filter` but two condition was not working because filtering and array loop at the same time.

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post').show();

    $('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        var $posts = $('.post').hide();
        var $elements = $('.menu-item').find('input:checked');

        if ($elements.length == 0)
        {
            $('.post').show(); return;
        }

        $posts.each(function () {
            var xPost = $(this);
            for (i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {
                if (xPost.hasClass($($elements[i]).attr('id'))) xPost.show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
article {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <h4>Profession</h4>

        <label for="doctor">Doctor</label><input id="doctor" type="checkbox" />

        <label for="engineer">Engineer</label><input id="engineer" type="checkbox" />

        <label for="pilot">Pilot</label><input id="pilot" type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <h4>City</h4>

        <label for="kochi">Kochi</label><input id="kochi" type="checkbox" />

        <label for="trivandrum">Trivandrum</label><input id="trivandrum" type="checkbox" />

        <label for="kannur">Kannur</label><input id="kannur" type="checkbox" />
    </li>
</ul>
<article class="post doctor kochi">doctor-kochi</article>
<article class="post engineer kannur">Engineer-kannur</article>
<article class="post pilot trivandrum">pilot-trivandrum</article>
<article class="post doctor kannur">doctor-kannur</article>
<article class="post enginner kochi">Engineer-kochi</article>
```

Comment: but this is not working...when it selects doctor and kochi it displays all doctors and all profession in kochi

Comment: I heard that it could be done using by combining array.every and array.some, but I don't know about these functions